# Unable to save specific file via dropbox saver

Tags: dropbox, file-transfer

I am trying to save Visual Studio Community Edition 2015 from this url (http://download.microsoft.com/download/D/4/5/D4510E81-0900-425F-85F3-A09AFFADFA45/vs2015.rc_com_enu.iso) to my dropbox, using this code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Saver</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.dropbox.com/static/api/2/dropins.js" id="dropboxjs" data-app-key="MY-APP-KEY"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="http://download.microsoft.com/download/D/4/5/D4510E81-0900-425F-85F3-A09AFFADFA45/vs2015.rc_com_enu.iso" class="dropbox-saver">Click here to save.</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

running on a local server. But this always returns the warning sign.

I tried with another file on some different domain and it worked. Can somebody point me to what I may be doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set up the [Dropbox Saver](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/dropins/saver) using JavaScript, you can implement an error callback that will give you more information in cases of failures like this.

I just did that with your [link](http://download.microsoft.com/download/D/4/5/D4510E81-0900-425F-85F3-A09AFFADFA45/vs2015.rc_com_enu.iso), and when doing that (after a good bit of time) I also see it fail, with the error message:

> Job timed out

So, unfortunately, it seems the hosting serving is serving too slowly and/or the file is too big, making the save job take longer than the Dropbox Saver will allow.